# Expo image picker pass selected image to the API

Tags: react-native, expo

Two Questions:

1. How can I convert the result of the image picker to get the blob to construct binary so that we can pass the formData to the api(required binary only)?
2. Expo image picker not returning exact type of the image. It just return "image" as the type of image.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the first Q is:
We can pass the uri of the image picker response in a below format:
We need to construct the formData

```
     let name = "anyName with proper extension";
     let imageType="image/${extensionoftheImage}";
      let formDataKeyValue = {
        uri: "fileToUpload.uri",
        name: name,
        type: imageType
      }
     let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file',
        formDataValue
      );
```

Pass the formData to the API.

Answer for second Q:
Expo only return type of the image as "image" only, this might be the bug in that so what we can do for now is extracting the extension for the image picker result uri.

e.g.

```
 let fileExtension = fileToUpload.uri.substr(fileToUpload.uri.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

this extension code can be used in first part of the answer to get the image  extension.